# Select a range of Time Stamp in SQL

Tags: sql, mysqli

Please help me in here.

```
SELECT TOP 200 [TimeStamp]        
      ,[Id]
      ,[Serial]
      ,[Server]
      ,[Message]
      ,[Station]
      ,ISNULL([P1],'Active Directory') as 'Category'
      ,ISNULL([P2],'Item Bold') as 'ItemName'    
  FROM [data].[dbo].[Message]    
  WHERE TimeStamp >= '2017-11-13' AND TimeStamp <= '2017-12-30'  
  ORDER BY TimeStamp Desc
```

I am trying to get data in a specific range of "TimeStamp", I have a UI where the user can select two timestamp for them to select the range (see code). But my problem is, for specific TimeStamp, there are lot of identical data. For example the "2017-12-30" has 5 entries, but they have different in data in terms of "Category".

Now my question is, how would I know what the user really actually pick from the "TimeStamp" though they have identical items.

Comment: How is this UI populated? Does it contain all of the records returned by your query?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Yes My Friend ! What happen is, it returns all the data of identical Timestamp, which is not I want. I just want, what the user select in my UI. Thanks !

Comment: You did not answer my question. What does the user actually select using the UI? Is it the start / end dates?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Im sorry, I miss understood. Yes, it selects the Start and End Dates, I used datagridview for this.

Comment: So, the user picks a date, for example `2017-12-30`. There are 5 different records having this date value. You want to know which one the user has selected. Is that right?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Yes that is right. I don't know what exact queryI I should use.

Comment: So, the user just picks a date and there are five records that correspond to this date. What is the intention of the user? Does he want to pick *any* of those 5 records? Does he want to select just a *specific* record?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Actually, not just 5 records, it is a thousands of TimeStamp records, and he will just pick the Start and End in timestamp, but there is a probability that what he picks has Identical values, that is why some of the records are returned though they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression expr.**

Use `DATE(expr)`

```
SELECT TOP 200 [TimeStamp]        
      ,[Id]
      ,[Serial]
      ,[Server]
      ,[Message]
      ,[Station]
      ,ISNULL([P1],'Active Directory') as 'Category'
      ,ISNULL([P2],'Item Bold') as 'ItemName'    
  FROM [data].[dbo].[Message]    
  WHERE DATE(TimeStamp) >= '2017-11-13' AND DATE(TimeStamp) <= '2017-12-30'  
  ORDER BY TimeStamp Desc
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! I Will try this.

Comment: Is It Working? @Henjoe

Comment: Hello Jay, it still gives me the same data.